# Different results on different machines tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, reproducible-research

I'm running a Tensorflow 1.12 code (I'm not using GPU). I have set

```
import os
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
os.environ['TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISTIC'] = '1'
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '42'

import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
    intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, 
    inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
np.random.seed(42)
tf.set_random_seed(42)

<<my code>>
```

If I run the code on the same hardware, the result is identical. However, if I run the code on different hardware (e.g. Xeon E5 vs Epyc Rome 7402), I git different results.

Could you please help me solve this problem?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow performance is a little dependent on hardware configuration also.

> The performance of TensorFlow Serving is highly dependent on the
> application it runs, the environment in which it is deployed and other
> software with which it shares access to the underlying hardware
> resources.

Read more from: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/performance

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
So, technically, there is no way to make a tensorflow model reproducible?